# left join query instead of not exists

Tags: sql, left-join, max, not-exists

I have a "not exists query" that perform poor. So I though that a "left join query" will perform better but thats not the case. I am running these queries in VBA.

here is my "not exists query"

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS t1
WHERE t1.ID_person = 1960081947465
and t1.ID_company <> 68550
and t1.FullTime + 26.3 >= 37.33 
and t1.Date <= 20130101
and t1.Code not in (31,28) 
and t1.FullTime < 100          
and not exists (
                  select * from MyTable t2 where 
                  t1.ID_person = t2.ID_person 
                  and t2.ID_company <> 68550
                  and t2.FullTime + 26.3 >= 37.33 
                  and t2.Date <= 20130101 
                  and t2.Code not in (31,28) 
                   and t1.Date< t2.Date 
                 )
```

And here is the way Im trying to achieve the same result but with a "left join Query"

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
 select * from MyTable t2 where
 and t2.ID_company <> 68550
 and t2.FullTime + 26.3 >= 37.33
 and t2.Date <= 20130101
 and t2.Code not in (31,28)
 ) subq
 ON t1.ID_person = subq.ID_person and t1.Date < subq.Date 
 WHERE t1.ID_person = 1960081947465
 and t1.ID_company <> 68550
 and t1.FullTime + 26.3 >= 37.33
 and t1.Date <= 20130101
 and t1.Code not in (31,28)
 and t1.FullTime < 100          
 and subq.ID_person IS NULL
```

Why is the "left join query" performing poorer? I thought that it will be faster. I have a third version of the same query but using "not in". The query is so similar to the "not exists query" that I dont think I need to post it here.

Can any one suggest a better/faster "left join query"???

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? `Left join ... where null` typically performs better in MySQL, while `not exists` typically performs better in some other RDBMSs (such as Oracle and SQLServer).

Comment: A mandatory read about this by Aaron Bertrand (Sql Server only): [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: It is Jet, im running the queries from vba/access

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you need indexes on all the columns that take part in the join/where clauses *in the same order* they appear in the `where` clause. Make sure you have the respective indices and both the `not exists` and the `join` should perform similarly and fast.

Comment: Yes, I have indeces on all columns in the where clause. But as mentioned before here, the way I left join makes no use of the indeces.